# Scrapy: How to add middleware to inrease RETRY_TIMES

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I am currently trying to crawl a website. The crawler works quite smoothly. However, after 3 to 4 hours of crawling the script sometimes crashes due to server/internet dropout.

This is the error message:

```
2019-09-27 10:53:46 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 448 pages (at 1 pages/min), scraped 4480 items (at 10 items/min)
2019-09-27 10:54:00 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://blogabet.com/tipsters/?f[language]=all&f[pickType]=all&f[sport]=all&f[sportPercent]=&f[leagues]=all&f[picksOver]=0&f[lastActive]=12&f[bookiesUsed]=null&f[bookiePercent]=&f[order]=followers&f[start]=4480> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2019-09-27 10:54:46 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 448 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 4480 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-09-27 10:55:00 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://blogabet.com/tipsters/?f[language]=all&f[pickType]=all&f[sport]=all&f[sportPercent]=&f[leagues]=all&f[picksOver]=0&f[lastActive]=12&f[bookiesUsed]=null&f[bookiePercent]=&f[order]=followers&f[start]=4480> (failed 2 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2019-09-27 10:55:46 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 448 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 4480 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-09-27 10:56:00 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET https://blogabet.com/tipsters/?f[language]=all&f[pickType]=all&f[sport]=all&f[sportPercent]=&f[leagues]=all&f[picksOver]=0&f[lastActive]=12&f[bookiesUsed]=null&f[bookiePercent]=&f[order]=followers&f[start]=4480> (failed 3 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2019-09-27 10:56:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (504) <GET https://blogabet.com/tipsters/?f[language]=all&f[pickType]=all&f[sport]=all&f[sportPercent]=&f[leagues]=all&f[picksOver]=0&f[lastActive]=12&f[bookiesUsed]=null&f[bookiePercent]=&f[order]=followers&f[start]=4480> (referer: https://blogabet.com/tipsters) ['partial']
2019-09-27 10:56:00 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <504 https://blogabet.com/tipsters/?f[language]=all&f[pickType]=all&f[sport]=all&f[sportPercent]=&f[leagues]=all&f[picksOver]=0&f[lastActive]=12&f[bookiesUsed]=null&f[bookiePercent]=&f[order]=followers&f[start]=4480>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2019-09-27 10:56:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

I think it would make sense to increase `RETRY_TIMES` from 2 (default) to 10. But I dont know how to add it to the settings.py and to which part of my code. You can find my code bellow.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Import Scrapy ist verpflichtend
import scrapy

# Import Request ist da, da die Header mitgeschickt werden muessen (haengt von der Webseite ab)
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.http import Request
from aufgehts.items import AufgehtsItem
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import re

class BlogmeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogme'


    def start_requests(self):

        url = "https://blogabet.com/tipsters/?f[language]=all&f[pickType]=all&f[sport]=all&f[sportPercent]=&f[leagues]=all&f[picksOver]=0&f[lastActive]=12&f[bookiesUsed]=null&f[bookiePercent]=&f[order]=picks&f[start]=0"

        headers={
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8,de;q=0.7',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Host': 'blogabet.com',
            'Referer': 'https://blogabet.com/tipsters',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }

        yield scrapy.http.Request(url, headers=headers)


    def parse(self, response):

        listenings = response.xpath('//*[@class="block row no-padding-lg tipster-block"]')

        for listening in listenings:
            username = listening.xpath('.//h3[@class="name-t u-db u-mb1"]/strong/text()').extract_first()
            link = listening.xpath('.//*[@class="e-mail u-db u-mb1 text-ellipsis"]/a/@href').extract_first()

            yield {'Username': username,
                'Link': link}

        next_page_number = response.xpath('//*[@class="btn btn-danger"]/@onclick').re('-?\d+')
        next_page_number = next_page_number[0]
        url = "https://blogabet.com/tipsters/?f[language]=all&f[pickType]=all&f[sport]=all&f[sportPercent]=&f[leagues]=all&f[picksOver]=0&f[lastActive]=12&f[bookiesUsed]=null&f[bookiePercent]=&f[order]=picks&f[start]="
        next_page_url= (url + next_page_number)

        if next_page_number:
            headers={
                    'Accept': '*/*',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8,de;q=0.7',
                    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                    'Host': 'blogabet.com',
                    'Referer': 'https://blogabet.com/tipsters',
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36',
                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                }
            yield scrapy.http.Request(next_page_url, headers=headers, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: You can just add `RETRY_TIMES=10` to your settings.py file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `RETRY_TIMES` directly in your spider code ([docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider))

```
....
class BlogmeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogme'

    custom_settings = {
    'RETRY_TIMES': 10,
     }

def start_requests(self):
...
```

Comment: mhh do I have to add something to the setting.py as well? It still stoped the script after the 3rd attempt ...Or do I have to use 'RETRY_TIMES ': '10 instead of just 10?

Comment: try `'RETRY_TIMES': 10` (I wrote extra space symbol after `RETRY_TIMES`)